# Access C# classes from VBA COM.Interop

Tags: c#, vba, com-interop

ERROR : property let procedure not defined and property get procedure did not return an object vba
And here is the relevant code:

```
namespace Entities
{
    [Guid("E65658F2-67C4-4F86-890C-62517EFB19AC")]
    [ComVisible(true)]
    public interface IFieldTags
    {
        [DispId(-4)]
        FieldTagsEnumerator GetEnumerator();
    }

    [Guid("472DDF54-E42D-4E6D-9D62-1507CDB2ED0A")]
    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDispatch)]
    [ComVisible(true)]
    public class FieldTags : IEnumerable, IFieldTags
    {

        private List<FieldTag> fieldTagsList;

        internal FieldTags(Document document, Tools tools)
        {
            this.constants = tools.Constants;
            this.document = document;
            this.fieldTagsList = GetFieldtagList();
        }

        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return (IEnumerator)GetEnumerator();
        }

        public FieldTagsEnumerator GetEnumerator()
        {
            return new FieldTagsEnumerator(this.fieldTagsList);
        }
    }


    public class FieldTagsEnumerator : IEnumerator
    {
        private readonly List<FieldTag> fieldTagsCollection;
        private int position = -1;

        public FieldTagsEnumerator(List<FieldTag> fieldTagsList)
        {
            fieldTagsCollection = fieldTagsList;
        }
    }
}
```

Generated .tlb using RegAsm.exe and Attached Entities.tlb to VBA

In VBA :

```
Dim objFieldTags As Entities.IFieldTags
// returns FieldTags type object in c#
Set objFieldTags = objDocument.GetNewRange(WordDocument.Range).FieldTags

For Each obj In objFieldTags
```

For Each causes error, Is this methodology correct? how can I use FieldTags in a loop ?

Comment: This is quite complex. Why don't you do something like this: https://pastebin.com/raw/ZSQCjVRu which seems to works

Answer (score 0):

I am no expert but recently solved(ish) this issue for a C# dictionary wrapper for VBA.

Here is how how I managed it for a c# wrapped dictionary.

```
private Dictionary<dynamic, dynamic> Host = new Dictionary<dynamic, dynamic>();

public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        foreach (KeyValuePair<dynamic, dynamic> myPair in Host)
        {
            yield return new KVPair(myPair.Key, myPair.Value);
        }
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
```

And for when I wrap my c# object in a vba class

```
// Allows a wrapped Kvp to be enumerated in VBA
public IEnumerator KvpEnum()
{
    foreach (KeyValuePair<dynamic, dynamic> myPair in Host)
    {
        yield return new KVPair(myPair.Key, myPair.Value);
    }
}
```

my full class is here  [Kvp: C# library for VBA that wraps a dictionary.](https://github.com/SteveLaycock/Kvp)